# Angular block Ui 0.2.2 showing an error "Cannot read property 'blockUI' of null"

Tags: angularjs

I have added Angular block Ui 0.2.2 version but it is not working. It shows error:

> Cannot read property 'blockUI' of null

**Error in console**
[image]

**Code**

```
sampleclick()  
{
    this.blockUI.start("My custom message");
    this.$timeout(function()
    {
        this.blockUI.stop(); 
    }, 2000);
}
```

I am using angular 1.5

Comment: You must show us more code. It seems that your code is bundled, maybe you forgot something in your bundler configuration, or in your dependencies injection

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-aria": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-block-ui": "^0.2.2",
}

Here i have imported the package in my app.js File as given below

import ngAria from 'angular-aria';
import blockUI from 'angular-block-ui';
import ngResource from 'angular-resource';

then i have injected blockUI as dependeny

angular.module('app', [
 
  uiRouter,
  ngAnimate,
  ngCookies,
  ngTouch,
  uiSelect,
  ngSanitize,
  ngMessages,
  ngAria,
  blockUI

])

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very likey in the timeout function:

```
this.$timeout(function() {
  this.blockUI.stop();
}, 2000);
```

You are using `this` within the inner anonymous function scope. 
There are two ways of solving this:

Use Arrow function (ES6)

```
this.$timeout(() => {
  this.blockUI.stop();
}, 2000);
```

Declare the outer scope as variable:

```
sampleclick() {
  var that = this;

  that.blockUI.start("My custom message");
  that.$timeout(function() { 
    that.blockUI.stop();
  }, 2000); 
}
```

Comment: i changed ma code to lambda function that error is cleared but still the Ui blocker not working

Comment: to solve this, we definitely need some more code. especially according to the blocker

Comment: Yes .. I have added angular block UI 0.2.2 using npm
after all i get these thing in my code 
 
"dependencies": { "angular": "~1.5.0", "angular-animate": "~1.5.0", "angular-aria": "~1.5.0",** "angular-block-ui": "^0.2.2"** } 
Here i have imported the package in my app.js File as given below import ngAria from 'angular-aria';** import blockUI from 'angular-block-ui';** import ngResource from 'angular-resource'; then i have injected blockUI as dependeny angular.module('app', [ uiRouter, ngAnimate, ngCookies, ngTouch, uiSelect, ngSanitize, ngMessages, ngAria, **blockUI **])

Comment: I ment, you should add, for example, the component controller in general or at least the constructor

Comment: class GeographicDefinitionCtrl {
  constructor( $q, commonSrv, countriesSrv, statesSrv, $window, $timeout, $uibModal,    CommonApiSrv,blockUI) {    
  this.$window = $window;  
 this.blockUI=blockUI;  
 this.$timeout=$timeout;  
sampleclick() {  
  this.blockUI.start("My custom message");  

  this.$timeout(() => {  
    this.blockUI.stop();  
  }, 2000);   
}    
}  
export default GeographicDefinitionCtrl;

Comment: are you calling the `sampleclick` function from your template? If yes, paste that line too, please.

Comment: <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="$ctrl.sampleclick()" style="padding-bottom: 4px;padding-top: 3px;font-size: 15px;">
                      Search
                    </button>
                  </div>

Comment: Ah! You defined the `sampleclick` function in your constructor. This might be the problem. Remove it from the constructor in declare it as a class function like: `class GeographicDefinitionCtrl { constructor(...) {} sampleclick() {...} }`

Comment: And you missed a closing `}` right before `export default GeographicDefinitionCtrl;`

Comment: then how can i block my ui from a function which is  defined inside the constructor?

Comment: assign it to this as well: `constructor(...) { this.sampleclick() {} }`

Comment: that was only a fraction of code that i have written in my controller only for your reference. that is a working template and i have to  block ui once the controller is pinging with the server using ajax requeasts

Comment: written this sampleclick  function for testing whether Blocker is working or not

Comment: I can't follow you. If this is not the working code, how could I find out, whats not working in your production code?

Comment: i need to block my UI once a server request is initiated until i get a response from server

Comment: It often help, if you try to produce a working fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/). Most problems solve if you try to reproduce them in a different environment.